# Do Reflections About Lines in 2-D Preserve Angle Measure for Figures?

Tags: geometry

I [read](http://www.cpalms.org/Public/PreviewResourceAssessment/Preview/59166) that reflections preserve angle measure but not distance because they are "flips".

> $\underline{\textbf{Question:}}$ So, is it true that a figure that is reflected about a line preserves angle measure?
>
> > I'm going to now explain why I do not think it is true.
> >     I'm sure there is a more succinct way to write this, but $\textbf{ANYTHING WRITTEN BELOW THIS IS NOT NEEDED TO ANSWER}$
> >     $\textbf{THIS QUESTION.}$ I'm just showing my work in case there is an error.

---

Explanation for Why Not True:

First, I'm going to come up with a valid equation that allows us to reflect a point $P:=(x_o, y_o)$ about a line $g(x):=mx+b$ where $m\neq 0$ (see bullet for end result). First, let's consider the figure below.

[image]

Since lines $t$ and $g$ are $\perp$, we know $t(x)=\frac{-1}{m}x+c$ where $c$ is some constant. Since $t(x_o)=y_o$, we know $-\frac{1}{m}x+c=y_o\implies c=y_o+\frac{1}{m}$. Thus, $t(x)=\frac{-1}{m}x+(y_o+\frac{1}{m})$ substituting $c$ back into our original equation. Now, we know $t(x_1)=g(x_1)\implies \frac{-1}{m}x_1+(y_o+\frac{1}{m})=mx_1+b\implies y_o+\frac{1}{m}x_o-b=(m+\frac{1}{m})x_1\implies x_1=\frac{y_o+\frac{1}{m}x_o-b}{(m+\frac{1}{m})}=\frac{y_o+\frac{1}{m}x_o-b}{\frac{m^2+1}{m}}.$ Thus, $g(x_1)=m(\frac{y_o+\frac{1}{m}x_o-b}{\frac{m^2+1}{m}})+b$. Now, we know looking at the midpoint that $(\frac{x_o+x'}{2},\frac{y_o+y'}{2})=(\underbrace{\frac{y_o+\frac{1}{m}x_o-b}{\frac{m^2+1}{m}}}_{=x_1},\underbrace{\frac{y_o+\frac{1}{m}x_o-b}{\frac{m^2+1}{m}}}_{=y_1})$.

This means $x'=2(\frac{y_o+\frac{1}{m}x_o-b}{\frac{m^2+1}{m}})-x_o$ and $y'=2(\frac{y_o+\frac{1}{m}x_o-b}{\frac{m^2+1}{m}})-y_o$.

$\bullet$ Hence, we know $x'=2\cdot (y_o+\frac{1}{m}x_o-b)\cdot (\frac{m}{m^2+1})-x_o$ and $y'=2\cdot (y_o+\frac{1}{m}x_o-b)\cdot (\frac{m}{m^2+1})-y_o$ are our last two equations.

---

As I have now shown how to reflect a point across a given line, I should be able to see the same angles preserved below using the transformation above. However, I do not with this example which is clearly shown in red. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reflection across a line is an isometry - a rigid motion. It preserves all distances between points and (therefore) all angles.

You don't really need formulas to see this. Cut a triangle out of cardboard. Now turn it over. All lengths and angles are the same. The only difference is that "clockwise" becomes "counterclockwise".

There must be an error somewhere in your linear algebra  - the obtuse triangle can't be a reflection of the acute one.

Comment: Thank you! I will check my algebra.

Comment: I already found an error. This answers my question.

Comment: Lol love the cardboard explanation, because it’s true.